# swift call object in view controller from another file

Tags: ios, swift

Question is:
I have an UIView at the Viewcontroller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var WorldMap: UIImageView!
```

so, how can I access this WorldMap from another swift file?

`let someView = Viewcontroller.WorldMap` - does not works (do not see it)

Comment: Is `Viewcontroller` the class or the instance? WorldMap doesn't appear to be static, so if `Viewcontroller` is the class, you can't access it like a static var. You have to use the instance name. `instance.WorldMap`.

Comment: Currently, it sounds like you're doing something referred to as MVC or Model, View, Controller. This pattern is great to start learning software engineering and mobile development. However, it doesn't scale very well or always allow for the best reuse.

Comment: If instead of putting the Map inside of the ViewController directly, but another class, you could pass around the instance of that class to multiple view controllers and reuse it in other locations.

Comment: Olo, thanks all a lot for quick response.  Currenly I re-study(I don't know, can I use this word) from C language. There is a some strange thinks at the Swift: I can't call variable(or object) from another file - is the first. Strange is that in ViewController I see all variables and functions from another files. But when I at the another file - not can access to the any variable or function at the viewController class. So, now at the another files I must create function with passed values - question is that solution is correct

Comment: I created a function at the ViewController  which I can see from the another file:    func withWorldMapInside() -> UIView{ let objectToPass = WorldMap! return objectToPass }  - but still can't do enything

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide more information on why you want to access this view?  You probably have an X-Y problem. Generally shouldn't access a view controller's views from outside that view controller. You should invoke a method to modify or obtain the data you need.

Answer (score -1):

create an extension of your viewcontroller class (the one that contains your IBoutlet)  in your other file like so:

```
class MyVC: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var WorldMap: UIImageView!


}

extension MyVC {
     //You can access WorldMap there
}
```

Comment: I learn Swift 2 months and this is the amazest way to use extension than I see. PS minus not by me

Comment: @Alek Szczęsnowicz nice to know if it helps, a +1 would be appreciated, i don’t get people added a -1, maybe because it’s a simple solution

Comment: unfortunately this not works. Try in different ways, but not.

Comment: @Alek Szczęsnowicz this should normally work if you copy the extension in an other file. you can access wordmap in the extension, but maybe your problem is different, maybe you didn’t mean swift file but meant another viewcontroller (as you see them in your story board)? More details are need.